# Ngx-bootstrap Tooltip : Change manually postion values

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript, ngx-bootstrap

I'm using ngx-bioostrap inside my **Angular 4** App.

i'm using **ngx-bootstrap Tooltip** widget :

Ater importing it i m using it like this in my component view :

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
        tooltip="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus."
        placement="right">
  Simple demo
</button>
```

As you can see , i'm using the **right** option

But that's not enough for me as i want to set its positions **left** and **top** to specific values.

I ve tried several ways ; for example using **jquery** to override its style by jquery like this:

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    $('.nomadis').mouseover(function () {
      $('bs-tooltip-container').css({'left': '100px' , 'top':'50px'});
    });
  }
```

Even with that ; the position of the tooltip **still in it first state**.

**Any ideas to adjust it position manually ??**

Answer (score 0):

**What I would have done**

1 - Inspect the element

2 - Note its class

3 - In your general style, override this class, with `!important` attributes if you must.

Comment: When you inspect it again, is your custom class overriden ? Or is it present at all ?

Comment: it s not even overrided , seems like the component impose its style